# How to convert last desired days to weeks in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, datetime

Hi i have a function who returns me the last 30 days from current day excluding current date. Function is below

```
function getLastNDays($days, $format = 'd-m-Y'){
    $m = date("m"); $de = date("d")-1; $y= date("Y");
    $dateArray = array();
    for($i=0; $i<=$days-1; $i++){

        $dateArray[] = date($format, mktime(0,0,0,$m,($de-$i),$y)); 
    }
    $dateArray[] = 'x';
    return array_reverse($dateArray);
}
```

so i am using this function

```
$sevenarr = getLastNDays(30);
```

and it is returning me this result

```
   Array
(
    [0] => x
    [1] => 19-06-2018
    [2] => 20-06-2018
    [3] => 21-06-2018
    [4] => 22-06-2018
    [5] => 23-06-2018
    [6] => 24-06-2018
    [7] => 25-06-2018
    [8] => 26-06-2018
    [9] => 27-06-2018
    [10] => 28-06-2018
    [11] => 29-06-2018
    [12] => 30-06-2018
    [13] => 01-07-2018
    [14] => 02-07-2018
    [15] => 03-07-2018
    [16] => 04-07-2018
    [17] => 05-07-2018
    [18] => 06-07-2018
    [19] => 07-07-2018
    [20] => 08-07-2018
    [21] => 09-07-2018
    [22] => 10-07-2018
    [23] => 11-07-2018
    [24] => 12-07-2018
    [25] => 13-07-2018
    [26] => 14-07-2018
    [27] => 15-07-2018
    [28] => 16-07-2018
    [29] => 17-07-2018
    [30] => 18-07-2018
)
```

So what i want now is to show the result days as weeks. so till now i am not able to figure it out how to do this with the upper function. please help me with some logic how can i update my function so i get the weeks of last desired days. For example there is last 30 days it will convert days into weeks

Output i want is

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            ['start-date'] => 18-07-2018
            ['end-date'] => 12-07-2018
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            ['start-date'] => 11-07-2018
            ['end-date'] => 5-07-2018
        )

     [2] => Array
        (
            ['start-date'] => 04-07-2018
            ['end-date'] => 28-06-2018
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            ['start-date'] => 27-06-2018
            ['end-date'] => 21-06-2018
        )
    [4] => Array
        (
            ['start-date'] => 20-06-2018
            ['end-date'] => 19-06-2018
        )
```

desired output

```
 [weekArray] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2018-06-19
                    [1] => 2018-06-20
                    [2] => 2018-06-21
                    [3] => 2018-06-22
                    [4] => 2018-06-23
                    [5] => 2018-06-24
                    [6] => 2018-06-25
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2018-06-26
                    [1] => 2018-06-27
                    [2] => 2018-06-28
                    [3] => 2018-06-29
                    [4] => 2018-06-30
                    [5] => 2018-07-01
                    [6] => 2018-07-02
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2018-07-03
                    [1] => 2018-07-04
                    [2] => 2018-07-05
                    [3] => 2018-07-06
                    [4] => 2018-07-07
                    [5] => 2018-07-08
                    [6] => 2018-07-09
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2018-07-10
                    [1] => 2018-07-11
                    [2] => 2018-07-12
                    [3] => 2018-07-13
                    [4] => 2018-07-14
                    [5] => 2018-07-15
                    [6] => 2018-07-16
                )

            [5] => Array
                (

                    [0] => 2018-07-17
                    [1] => 2018-07-18
                    [2] => 2018-07-19
                )

        )
```

Comment: can you give us an example of expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check below function to get the days range into weeks. I have considered Sunday as first day of week.

```
    <?php
    function getLastNDays($days, $format = 'Y-m-d'){

        $retunData = array();

        $m = date("m"); $de = date("d")-1; $y= date("Y");
        $dateArray = array();
        for($i=0; $i<=$days-1; $i++){

            $dateArray[] = date($format, mktime(0,0,0,$m,($de-$i),$y)); 
        }
        //$dateArray[] = 'x';
        $resultArray =  array_reverse($dateArray);

        // After get the date Range find out Statrt & End date
        $start_date = $resultArray[0];
        $end_date = $resultArray[count($resultArray)-1];

        $from_date = new DateTime($start_date);
        $to_date = new DateTime($end_date);
        $interval = new DateInterval('P1D');
        $dateRange = new DatePeriod($from_date, $interval, $to_date);

        $week_number = 1;
        $weekArray = array();

        foreach ($dateRange as $key => $date) {
            $weekArray[$week_number][] = $date->format('Y-m-d');

            $mod = $key%7;
            if($mod == 6){
              $week_number++;
            }  

            /*
            if ($date->format('w') == 6) {
                $week_number++;
            }
            */
        }
        $retunData['weekArray'] = $weekArray;

        //Get the Start & End Date each week.   
        $weekrange = array_map(function($w) {
            return 'start: ' . array_shift($w) 
                . ', end: ' . array_pop($w); },
        $weekArray);

        $retunData['weekRange'] = $weekrange;

        return $retunData;
    }

    $retunData = getLastNDays(30);  // Call your custom function.

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($retunData);
    exit;

    ?>

    Your Output will be as per the date range.



   Array
(
    [weekArray] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2018-06-20
                    [1] => 2018-06-21
                    [2] => 2018-06-22
                    [3] => 2018-06-23
                    [4] => 2018-06-24
                    [5] => 2018-06-25
                    [6] => 2018-06-26
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2018-06-27
                    [1] => 2018-06-28
                    [2] => 2018-06-29
                    [3] => 2018-06-30
                    [4] => 2018-07-01
                    [5] => 2018-07-02
                    [6] => 2018-07-03
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2018-07-04
                    [1] => 2018-07-05
                    [2] => 2018-07-06
                    [3] => 2018-07-07
                    [4] => 2018-07-08
                    [5] => 2018-07-09
                    [6] => 2018-07-10
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2018-07-11
                    [1] => 2018-07-12
                    [2] => 2018-07-13
                    [3] => 2018-07-14
                    [4] => 2018-07-15
                    [5] => 2018-07-16
                    [6] => 2018-07-17
                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2018-07-18
                )

        )

    [weekRange] => Array
        (
            [1] => start: 2018-06-20, end: 2018-06-26
            [2] => start: 2018-06-27, end: 2018-07-03
            [3] => start: 2018-07-04, end: 2018-07-10
            [4] => start: 2018-07-11, end: 2018-07-17
            [5] => start: 2018-07-18, end: 
        )

)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Let me check if it is working for me or not

Comment: As you can see in your output of `weekArray`. Inside it in first array only 5 values are showing. What i want there is seven hope you are getting me

Comment: So all of sudden i look deep into it and found that because of considered Sunday as first day it is creating problem is there any way by which we can considered first array value as first day of the week then start loop from there

Comment: Please check updated answer. You need to update the foreach loop.